# Use imagick with S3 AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, imagick

These are my first steps with AWS S3, so and my goal is to use `imagick` for manipulating the image before I upload to S3 AWS.

I use this function for resize and scale the image (works perfect on output browser):

```
function resizeImg($img, $width, $height) {

    $i = new Imagick($img);

    $gig = $i->getImageGeometry();

    // crop the image
    if(($gig['width']/$width) < ($gig['height']/$height)) {

        $i->cropImage($gig['width'], floor($height * $gig['width'] / $width), 0, (($gig['height'] - ($height * $gig['width'] / $width)) / 2));

    } else {

        $i->cropImage(ceil($width * $gig['height'] / $height), $gig['height'], (($gig['width'] - ($width * $gig['height'] / $height)) / 2), 0);
    }

    $i->ThumbnailImage($width, $height, true);

    $i->setImageFormat("jpeg");
    $i->setImageCompressionQuality(90);

    $i->getimageblob(); // I tried it with and without getimageblob

    return $i;
}
```

Thats my attempt, Upload to S3:

```
$tmpImg = $_FILES['inputImage']['tmp_name'];

$newImgFile = resizeImg($tmpImg, 100, 100); 

$s3->putObjectFile($newImgFile, BUCKET_NAME, $newfilename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

But I get this error:

> Warning: S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: ���� in.....

What I`m doing wrong?

Is imagick not compatible with S3 AWS?

Or is there a better way?

And my next goal is to put different image resizes to S3, e.g 100x100, 300x300.... from same input file, but of course I have to solve before the first goal.

**EXTRA:**

With this  solution from here:
[PHP Imagick: Write Image directly to Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286222/php-imagick-write-image-directly-to-amazon-s3)

I get this Error:

> Warning: S3::putObject(): [SignatureDoesNotMatch] The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

If I do this: `$new = urlencode($new);` or `$new = strtolower($new);`  ...Works to upload but no readable!

The error came from extra spaces or slashes in there, so far as I have understood

And if its important,  here the Url from the image in S3

> https->awsCount.xxxx.xxxxx/img.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxx&Expires=1383787878&Signature=xxxx&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEGAasAJlJXrt/7FPf84wE9stfgBfEoWaPMDHlubQBlQ6oMY6sNMT4cizkEm9khypHulLB/zJ%2BbqqAErvFBKKs2I9bKDBzrKYKhgRn%2Bta057CZaLougsxHLRGquhd5H26br/Odkq98%2BoDTnfK0LHFa9vYbX6sXDIzCSHcZx4%2B5o0y3cKlxCMsYLqw6wYD1DNjJ%2BHlWWuh%2B6V0FtpbYaErB1XUZfRRZdx3ZPEOvyZxQS7uzP8C3B1nK0wo3uqqSAhn9PPtQt5jrRutYRao2KugxK8TbkZbr/v5NOYSbpc%2BmI2iYYrUjylqgenzf85Avss0CA1GfOzg%2BMs2/TQ7evH7epr09B8Vyd89Gk1XQpVMyrTSvbzDYE8UCcgrUrXgdHTYWdGLVZ%2BBHzft9nHtNhggePD6AXMuIP%2Ba6ZMF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have the answer, I show the whole code for each one:

```
if (!empty($_FILES["input_file"])) {    

        if ($_FILES["input_file"]["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

            echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
            exit;
        }    

        // Move/Copy from temporary file to local file

        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input_file"]["tmp_name"],
                'local_temp_file_directory/' . $_FILES["input_file"]["name"]);

        if (!$success) {

            echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
            exit;
        }    
    }

    // I make a function to get the local file and save the edited file

    function resizeImg($img_from_local_file, $width, $height, $pathToSaveImg) {

        $i = new Imagick($img_from_local_file);
        $gig = $i->getImageGeometry();

        if(($gig['width']/$width) < ($gig['height']/$height)) {

            $i->cropImage($gig['width'], floor($height * $gig['width'] / $width), 0, (($gig['height'] - ($height * $gig['width'] / $width)) / 2));

        } else {

            $i->cropImage(ceil($width * $gig['height'] / $height), $gig['height'], (($gig['width'] - ($width * $gig['height'] / $height)) / 2), 0);
        }

        $i->ThumbnailImage($width, $height,true);
        $i->setImageFormat("jpeg");
        $i->setImageCompressionQuality(90);
        $i->writeImage($pathToSaveImg);
        return $i->getimage();
    }

    // Call the resizeImg function

    resizeImg("local_temp_file_directory/".$_FILES["input_file"]["name"], 40, 40, "local_temp_file_directory/resized_".$_FILES["input_file"]["name"]);

    $s3->putObject(
        S3::inputFile("local_temp_file_directory/resized_".$_FILES["input_file"]["name"]),
        BUCKET_NAME, 
        "make_a_new_image_name".date("his").".jpg", 
        S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, 
        array(), 
        array("Content-Type"=>'image/jpeg'));

 // Remove the temporary local file
 unlink("local_temp_file_directory/".$_FILES["input_file"]["name"]);
 unlink("local_temp_file_directory/resized_".$_FILES["input_file"]["name"]);
```

Thats it... Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put an object from S3 from a file (putObjectFile takes a file name as an argument) but you're giving the image blob as a parameter, instead of a file name.

You should do something like this:
In resizeImg:

```
return $i-> getimageblob(); //(this is just an assumption)
```

For uploading to S3, something similar to this:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();   
$s3->batch()->create_object(__BUCKET__,$filename, array(
                'body' => $object,
                'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
                'contentType' => $contentType,
                'storage' => AmazonS3::STORAGE_REDUCED
                ));
$file_upload_response = $s3->batch()->send();
```

Note that this is using the PHP SDK V1 (not sure if you're using V2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use SDK V2. Let me do a few tests and I will tell you how it works...

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your help! I have answer my question self! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can doing these :

```
    $outFile = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/uploads/imageWithImagick.png';
    $url = "http//......";
    $img = new Imagick();
    $dir = "images/profile";
    $uploader = $this->get('core_storage.uploader');
    $width = 300;
    $height = 500;
    $compression = 90;
    $imageFormat = "jpeg";
    $uploader->uploadImagick($url,$img,$outFile,$width,$height,$dir,$imageFormat,$compression);
```

and the function :

```
public function uploadImagick($url,$img,$outFile,$width,$height,$dir,$imageFormat,$compression)
{
    $handle = fopen($url, 'rb');
    $img->readImageFile($handle);
    $gig = $img->getImageGeometry();

    if(($gig['width']/$width) < ($gig['height']/$height)) {

        $img->cropImage($gig['width'], floor($height * $gig['width'] / $width), 0, (($gig['height'] - ($height * $gig['width'] / $width)) / 2));

    } else {

        $img->cropImage(ceil($width * $gig['height'] / $height), $gig['height'], (($gig['width'] - ($width * $gig['height'] / $height)) / 2), 0);
    }
    $img->thumbnailImage($width,$height);
    $img->setImageFormat($imageFormat);
    $img->setImageCompressionQuality($compression);
    $img->writeImage($outFile);
    // Generate a unique filename based on the date and add file extension of the uploaded file
    $filename = sprintf('%s/%s.%s', $dir, uniqid(), $imageFormat);
    $adapter = $this->filesystem->getAdapter();
    $adapter->write($filename, file_get_contents($outFile));
    unlink($outFile);
    return $filename;
}
```